# Accessing nuxt $store inside Dynamic Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm developing a Promise-based modal component which provides the possibility of specifing a component as body of the modal itself. To achieve that result, I thought that a good solution would be using a dynamic component inside the modal template.
However, inside a NUXT application, if the component refers to the Vuex instance (this.$store), it turns out to be undefined (or better there is no $store object attribute). In the same way, any injection done inside plugins results undefined (e.g. inject('api', api) create the attribute $api, but it results undefined).
If I just use the component in the 'standard' way (e.g. placing it inside the page or another component template), everything works fine.

There should be some 'extra injection' that I should do before passing the component in a programmatic way.

Can anyone help me?

The NUXT project structure (simplified):

- /pages/index.vue
- /plugins/api.js
- /store/auth.js
- /components/HelloComponent.vue

*/plugins/api.js*

```js
let api = {}

api.call = function (request, auth, unpack, axios = this.axios) {
  if (!request) Error('backend.js:call invalid params:', request, auth, unpack, axios)

  if (auth) {
    if (request.headers)
      request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.auth.accessToken
    else
      request.headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.auth.accessToken }
  }
  return axios(request).then((response) => unpack ? response.data : response)
}

api.getAPI = function (api, params, auth = true, unpack = true) {
  if (!api) Error('api.js:getAPI invalid params:', api)
  console.log('api.js:getAPI api:', api)
  return this.call({ method: 'get', url: api, params: params }, auth, unpack)
}

api.postAPI = function (api, params, data, auth = true, unpack = true) {
  if (!api) Error('api.js:postAPI invalid params:', api, data)
  console.log('api.js:postAPI api:', api)
  return this.call({ method: 'post', url: api, params: params, data: data }, auth, unpack)
}


/*******************************************************/
/*         NUXT plugin and reference injection         */
/*******************************************************/

export default function (context, inject) {

  console.log('[CALL] api.js')

  /* assign global $axios instance */
  api.axios = context.$axios

  /* assign auth instance to access tokens */
  api.auth = context.store.state.auth

  /* inject backend reference into application instance */
  inject('api', api)
}
```

*/pages/index.vue*

```js
<template>
  <div>
  
    <span>
      {{ $store.auth.state.name }} // -> Displays 'Chuck'
    </span>
    
    /* Object.keys(this).includes('$store): false'; Object.keys(this).includes('$auth): true' */
    <component :is="cComponent" /> // -> this.$store is undefined; auth: undefined
    
    <hello-component /> // -> Displays 'Chuck'; auth: Object {...}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloComponent from '../components/HelloComponent.vue'
export default {

  components: {
    HelloComponent
  },
  
  created () {
    this.$store.commit('auth/setName', 'Chuck')
  },
   
  computed: {
    cComponent () {
      return HelloComponent
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

*/components/HelloComponent.vue*

```js
<template>
  <span>
    {{ $store.auth.state.name }}
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  created() {
    console.log('auth:', this.$auth)
  }
  
}
</script>
```

*/store/auth.js*

```js
export const state = () => ({
  accessToken: null,
  refreshToken: null,
  name: null,
})

export const mutations = {

  setAccessToken(state, token) {
    console.info('auth.js:setAccessToken', token)
    state.accessToken = token
  },

  setRefreshToken(state, token) {
    console.info('auth.js:setRefreshToken', token)
    state.refreshToken = token
  },

  setName(state, name) {
    console.info('auth.js:setName', name)
    state.user = name
  },

}
```

Comment: show code, otherwise its impossible to tell

Comment: I posted a simple code that replicates the problem. However, as you can see, the problem appears when you refer to NUXT global variables inside a programmatically created component. My thought is that the NUXT inject function doesn't affect this kind of components.

Comment: Can u create a minimal reproduction on codesandbox? I cant reproduce it. Here example with dynamic component and store in it https://codesandbox.io/s/20x6m79jzp

Comment: The codesandbox you provided gives me a little error and it does not print the logs inside the mounted methods. I modified part of your example to fit my needs and surprisingly it seems to work. However when placing such a code in my local project the problem comes back. So I'll investigate in order to reproduce such issue on codesandbox and share it with you.

Comment: Github repo with problem can work too for reproduction

Answer (score 1):

if you have no access of **this pointer** in Nuxt project, And you really need to access **store**, then simply use

**window.$nuxt.$store** instead of **this.$store**;

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I would like to use a component both in a static and dynamic way. So I thing that using **window.$nuxt.$store** inside static-declared component is a bit tricky because one can directly use **this.$store**. On the other side, it is impossible to know if a user would use a component in a dynamic fashon, implying that she/he must be aware of such a issue (which is not a portable solution).

Comment: what? Thats not correct. you have access to this in nuxt. The only place where u dont have access to this is asyncData/fetch